# подскажите где ошибка в коде(expression result unused [-Wunused-value])

Tags: c

Подскажите, почему возникает данная ошибка при компиляции. по логике вроде всё должно работать.
сам код

```
 #include <unistd.h>
 int ft_putchar(char c)
 {
    write(1, &c, 1);
    return (0);
 }

void ft_print_alphabet(void)
{
char ch[]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
int i;
i=0;
while(i<26)
  {
  ft_putchar(ch[i]);
  i++;
}
  }
int main()
{
  ft_print_alphabet;//вот на этой строке возникает ошибка
  return (0);
}
```

Вроде создал массив
заполнил его,
с помощью функии печатаю их в одну строку, почему компилятор говорит тчо результат неиспользуется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `ft_print_alphabet` пишите `ft_print_alphabet()`. Если написать без скобок, то это будет просто адрес функции. А просто сам по себе адрес функции ничего не значит.